# The vertical spacing between the first and the second line in the section formatted with \titleformat

Tags: spacing, titlesec, strut

Why is the vertical spacing between the first and the second line in the section greater than the vertical spacing between the rest of the section in this MWE?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}
  [display]
  {\fontsize{26}{15}\selectfont}
  {\thesection}
  {0mm}
  {}

\titlespacing*{\section}{0mm}{*0}{0mm}


\begin{document}

\section{PPPPPPPP AAAAAAA VVVIVCCC IA OOOOOIO PPPPPIP PPPPPPPP AAAAAAA VVVIVCCC IA OOOOOIO IA OOOOOIO PPPPPIP PPPPPPPP AAAAAAA VVVIVCCC IA OOOOOIO IA OOOOOIO PPPPPIP PPPPPPPP AAAAAAA VVVIVCCC IA OOOOOIO PPPPPIP}

\vspace{3cm}

\fontsize{26}{15}\selectfont PPPPPPPP AAAAAAA VVVIVCCC IA OOOOOIO PPPPPIP PPPPPPPP AAAAAAA VVVIVCCC IA OOOOOIO IA OOOOOIO PPPPPIP PPPPPPPP AAAAAAA VVVIVCCC IA OOOOOIO IA OOOOOIO PPPPPIP PPPPPPPP AAAAAAA VVVIVCCC IA OOOOOIO PPPPPIP

\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT** Note that `\fontsize{26}{15}\selectfont` is used in both `\titleformat` and the `document` but their impact is different.

Comment: That is because of your font size command in `\titleformat`.

Comment: I know that, it is there on purpose. Note it is in the `document` but there are no spacing issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `titlesec` inserts an strut. Just write:

```
\usepackage[nostruts]{titlesec}
```

See the manual for further details.

Comment: Excellent! I do not know how I missed it. Have you considered having something like `allstruts` that will add strut to every line?

Comment: Increase the baselineskip. First lines are special in that the space above them is removed in some contexts. Why are you setting such a low baselineskip?

Comment: There was no special reason for such, I probably noticed the spacing issue with some other (more appropriate) baselineskip.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your fontsize command in `\titleformat`. Unrelated: I don't understand the reason behind your `\titlespacing` command, which enforces adding `\vspace` command before the section body.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}
  [display]
  {\fontsize{26}{0}\selectfont}
  {\thesection}
  {2mm}
  {}

\titlespacing*{\section}{0mm}{*0}{0mm}

\begin{document}

\section{PPPPPPPP AAAAAAA VVVIVCCC IA OOOOOIO PPPPPIP PPPPPPPP AAAAAAA VVVIVCCC IA OOOOOIO IA OOOOOIO PPPPPIP PPPPPPPP AAAAAAA VVVIVCCC IA OOOOOIO IA OOOOOIO PPPPPIP PPPPPPPP AAAAAAA VVVIVCCC IA OOOOOIO PPPPPIP}

\vspace{3cm}

\fontsize{26}{15}\selectfont PPPPPPPP AAAAAAA VVVIVCCC IA OOOOOIO PPPPPIP PPPPPPPP AAAAAAA VVVIVCCC IA OOOOOIO IA OOOOOIO PPPPPIP PPPPPPPP AAAAAAA VVVIVCCC IA OOOOOIO IA OOOOOIO PPPPPIP PPPPPPPP AAAAAAA VVVIVCCC IA OOOOOIO PPPPPIP

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Modifying the fontsize is there on purpose. `\titlespacing` is not relevant here, ignore it. Note the different behavior of `\fontsize{26}{15}\selectfont PPPPPPPP AAA...` in the `document` and the section.

Comment: I noted that \ I guess there's something in tyhe internals of titlesec that explains this behaviour,. However `\fontsize{26}{0}` (or `{26}{1}` if you prefer) seems to solve the problem, if I've well understood what you're rying to obtain.

Comment: I am trying to find the root cause of different behavior of `\fontsize{26}{15}`, and eventually fix it.